# Golang Rabbit MQ Fanout Exchange Multiple Consumers

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I am publishing messages in fanout exchange from Java application. I am able to receive message in multiple consumer in Java. I have 2 consumers in golang app but only one of the consumer (alternatively ) is receiving the message (Not both of them for a published message).

```
func HandleMessageFanout1(){

    conn := system.EltropyAppContext.RabbitMQConn

    channel, err := conn.Channel()

    if(err!=nil){
        log.Println(err)
    }
    //forever := make(chan bool)



    deliveries,err := channel.Consume(
        "example.queue", //queue
        "qw",
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil)

    if(err!=nil){
        log.Println(err)
    }

    go func() {

        for d := range deliveries {
            log.Printf("Message recived in fanout 1")
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
        }
    }()

    //<-forever

}
```

//2nd Consumer

```
package consumer

import (
    "github.com/eltropy/shehnai/backend/golang/common-packages/system"
    log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

    func HandleMessageFanout2() {

        conn := system.EltropyAppContext.RabbitMQConn

        channel, err := conn.Channel()

        if (err!=nil) {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        //forever := make(chan bool)

        deliveries, err := channel.Consume(
            "example.queue", //queue
            "q2",
            true,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            nil)

        if (err!=nil) {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        go func() {
            for d := range deliveries {
                log.Printf("Message recived in fanout 2")
                log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
            }
        }()

        //<-forever

    }
```

I am using https://github.com/streadway/amqp library for rabbit mq.

Answer (score 1):

On the channel type, before you publish, declare an exchange like this:

```
err = channel.ExchangeDeclare(
  "example.queue",   // name
  "fanout", // type
  true,     // durable
  false,    // auto-deleted
  false,    // internal
  false,    // no-wait
  nil,      // arguments
)
```

See the [official RabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-go.html).